Twig code for CKEditor page break
I moved a bunch of sites from Redactor to CKEditor and having issues with page breaks not working. This is the Twig code I used with Redactor:
{{ entry.body.getPage(1) }}

That no longer works with CKEditor - using the code above it returns null. I tried deleting the original page break and adding a new one within CDEditor, but it still returns null.
I know I can use the 'split' filter to get 'page 1', but that seems like a step backwards from the more elegant approach of the past.
I cannot find anything in Craft docs or CKEditor docs that helps, so reaching out to you good folks for some advice!

I didn't know the that the Craft Redactor plugin had this method for pagebreaks, I don't think it was ever documented. In any case, this method apparently was implemented in the FieldData class of the Craft Redactor plugin as a convenience method. However, the corresponding FieldData class in the CKEditor plugin does not have a similar method. So it looks like this feature is not supported by the CKEditor plugin, and you will indeed have to implement it yourself.
You can take a look at the implementation of the Redactor class for inspiration. However, it looks like CKEditor stores page breaks in a different format than Redactor did, so keep that in mind.
